# how to get http jersey response status before parsing to dto?

Tags: java, rest, http, jersey, jersey-client

my code used to be:

```
ClientResponse clientResponse = webResource.path("routingRequest")
                    .queryParam("at", rr.at)
                    .get(ClientResponse.class);
```

I added:

```
RoutingResponse routingResponse = webResource.path("routingRequest")
                    .queryParam("at", rr.at)
                    .get(ClientResponse.class)
                    .getEntity(RoutingResponse.class);
```

How can I get the http result code, now when I don't even get the `ClientResponse.class`

How would you get this status?

Comment: 1) You're first bit of code won't compile `get(ClientResponse.class)` will return a `ClientResponse`. 2) Get both the status code and `RoutingResponse` from the `ClientResponse`. `clientResponse.getEntity(RoutingResponse.class)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason why you cannot read the client response and the entity body in the same breath.

```
    ClientConfig cc = new DefaultClientConfig();
    cc.getProperties().put(
            ClientConfig.PROPERTY_FOLLOW_REDIRECTS, true);
    Client c = Client.create(cc);
    WebResource r = c.resource("https://my_url");
    ClientResponse response = r.get(ClientResponse.class);
    EntityTag e = response.getEntityTag();
    String entity = response.getEntity(String.class);
    System.out.println("The response status is " + response.getStatus());
    System.out.println("The enttiy body is " + entity);
```